# Altium Designer: Unconnected hidden power pin not detected by ERC

Tags: power, altium, pins

In Altium I set power pins to hidden in my component library, but I leave the "Connect to" empty (this is because I do not always connect the power pins to the same nets. Power pins can be connected to VCC, VDD, VEE, 3V3, GND... depending on where the component is used).
I set Unconnected Power pin to report an error in the connection matrix, but at Altium they hid the hidden pins so well that not even their ERC tool can detect they are unconnected! No error is reported during the ERC in the schematic. This is really annoying!
Moving to the PCB, no net is assigned to those power pins. To me those are unconnected power pins (they are defined as type power in the component) and they shall be detected during the ERC. (In fact, non-hidden unconnected power pins are detected by the ERC).

Suppose someone else is taking care of the PCB design... those unconnected pins may remain as such till the board manufacturing phase. Not good at all.

The obvious solution is to fill in the "Connect to" field of the power pins in the schematic. But suppose one forgets that step... The ERC shall detect such oversight!

Trying to make my question clearer:
The Altium manual states:

*"For a multi-part component, the power net connections should ideally be assigned through use of Part Zero. For each pin that is required to connect to a power net in this way, simply enable the Hide option, leave the Connect To field blank, and set the Part Number field to 0."*

I have followed this procedure. The problem is that there appears to be no way to get the ERC to detect that the "Connect To" field has been left blank in a component placed in a schematic (I mean not in the library).
Setting "Nets with only one pin" to error does not trigger any error for unconnected hidden pins as well. It seems that some ERC rules are not applied to hidden pins.

How can I get the Altium ERC to detect unconnected hidden power pins?

Comment: I've never used Altium -- how do you then connect a hidden power pin to a net of your choosing?

Comment: See last two lines (edited): "The obvious solution..."

Comment: OK, then I have to ask: Why hide that information in the first place, given that the whole point of a schematic diagram is to document details like that?

Comment: We show where the power pins are connected with graphical symbols, for example with a rail above and below the opamp symbol, where the rails are named VCC and GND, for example. This makes the schematic clearer, considering that some opamps may have other pins, besides inputs and outputs (offset, shutdown pin...)

Comment: So who's responsible for making sure the "graphical symbol" agrees with the actual pin property? In other EDA packages I've used, such symbols are actually part of the component in the library, and constitute NON-hidden pins on the component. ERC handles it just fine, and there's no chance of inconsistent information.

Comment: Well, this is the way they have been working for the last 40 years at the company I work with. You are right, the "graphical symbol" and the actual connection of the power pin can be inconsistent. They have to be manually checked.

Comment: Which brings us back to your question -- that manual check should also be verifying  that the property is set at all. So what is your actual problem?

Comment: ERC checks cannot detect all design flaws, and in a way, hiding all power pins on your components is a massive design methodology flaw.  Your argument is that ERC should find it anyway, but not when they design for common use case.  Tell your company to start doing it the right way for the next 40 years.

Comment: Well, my point is that the ERC shall detect unconnected power pins, regardless of their hidden status. I can't understand why hidden pins are ignored. Altium has been around for many, many years, so I would have expected that when one sets it to detect unconnected power pins, the hidden ones would be checked too!

Comment: What is your actual question? Or did you just need to let off some steam about an issue you have with Altium?

Comment: "I would have expected that when one sets it to detect unconnected power pins, the hidden ones would be checked too!" But why when they're hidden and Altium doesn't know what they are supposed to be connected to. It's a manual connection when they are hidden. It's for you to decide if they are connected to a net or just simply not connected. You want Altium to differentiate that? For others that may be annoying to show up in the ERC.

Comment: Last time I used mentor graphics DxDesigner it had this feature and a senior engineer loved it but didn't always do it and didn't tell anyone. I wanted to rip my hair out. find out how to change this practice in your own company!

Comment: There is a way to edit the warning and error settings. Too lazy to check the details. I am almost positive you can fix this the way you want by editing your preferences. An unconnected power net should probably be an error rather than a warning. I agree with the others that invisible connections are undesirable, and I would not hide power pins. Also never hide net names, in altium or any other CAD system. Once I inherited a schematic where someone had give what looked like a GND symbol a different net name. Had to rework the first batch of prototypes to connect the net to GND.

Comment: What about this: Go "Project," "Project Options," click on "Error Reporting," tab, then configure "Nets with only one pin" as an error or warning? Does that cause it to warn you when you have an unconnected power net?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited the second part of my post.

Comment: @DigitalNinja: the hidden status of a pin in the schematic does not change the pin on the actual component! If the component datasheet requires the pin to be connected, this connection shall be checked regardless the hide property of the pin in the component symbol. If it is a power pin and you set the ERC to detect unconnected power pins, it is because you would like to avoid having unconnected power pins on your board. To me, the ERC should not ignore hidden pins, because they are not hidden at all on the board!

Comment: KiCad has this same hidden pin (anti)feature. I don't know why anyone would want it. ERC does still work on them at least...

Comment: @tomatoma I agree with you 100%, I am shocked that Altium does not seem to warn you of unconnected power pins just because they are hidden. I would contact Altium tech support (they are very good) and ask them about it. It seems like a bug to me, and a fairly serious one at that. I ran into this exact problem on one of my most recent boards. I had the boards manufactured only to find that the net for one of the hidden power pins was never set. I had to bodge a wire in to make the connection.

Comment: @tomatoma "the hidden status of a pin in the schematic does not change the pin on the actual component!" Of course it doesn't, but Altium doesn't know what the data sheet says. You can label a pin anything you want and connect it to any net that you want. Since the pin was made hidden it's the user's responsibility to select a connection using the "connect to" box. Anyway, I'm not sure why you just aren't asking Altium for an answer? They have a support center. Also, have you fully explored configuring the ERC? Maybe this will help: http://www.denatechnologies.com/erc-altium/

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is, why would you make a pin hidden and not connect it? That just seems like a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: The only way it ever makes sense to hide power pins is if you ALSO generate a report included with the schematic that tells what power net each of the hidden pins is connected to. This is an ancient and terrible practice from back when you only had a +5V rail.